# Cannot individually delete phone number from contact list

Tags: contacts, delete

I have one or two contacts on the People app's list with two or more duplicated phone numbers.

How do I delete them individually, without deleting the whole contact ?

I don't see this option on the edit button on the top right corner

Screenshot:
http://1drv.ms/1RkfK8K

Android 4.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the menu button at the top, then edit. When it lets you edit the numbers, click on the number you want to remove. Then you should see a minus sign on the right, click on that. It should remove that number. Then save. Hope this helps.

Edit. Here is a screenshot of how it looks on my phone:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Yes ! It works. I don't believe I didn't see this button ! Thanks. Problem solved.

Comment: Glad it worked for ya. =)

Comment: It didn't work for me, it was so annoying that such basic thing will not work. I had to delete the contact and recreate with only one phone number.

Comment: Won't work for me either on the contact screen there are 2 numbers the right one and the wrong one, I hit edit and it only shows the right one on that screen to correct!